# declaring global variables in yacc

Tags: c, global-variables, yacc

I have a few source code files, such hashtable.c and such. The main issue is that when I write my main.c as such:

```
#include "tokens.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror(char *errorMsg)
{
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", errorMsg);
}


main() 
{
  yyparse();
  hsh = createHashtable();

}
```

And at the top of my yacc file (parser.y), I want to declear a hash table as such:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tokens.h"
#include "ast.c"


struct hashtable *hsh;
.............................
..............................
```

However I am getting this error.

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:24: error: ‘hsh’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:24: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:24: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I am rather naive while it comes to C programming, any assistance will be greatful

Answer (score 6):

You need an `extern struct hashtable* hsh;` in your `main.c`

Comment: can you be a little more specific, i'm confused

Comment: You need to declare in your main.c that the symbol 'hsh' is defined in some other compilation unit.  This is accomplished with the 'extern' modifier; see http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_use_of_extern_in_C

Comment: It would be better if the user put the extern declaration in a header file and included that header in both the grammar and the main program.  One of the two files should actually define the variable - doing it in the grammar is fine.